# How to upload a photo and display it in Edit and Show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on creating student registration form. I wanted to upload student photo, so how to upload and display the photo in new, edit and show page?

OS: fedora 22

Please tell me how to upload the photo in the registration form.

Comment: Have you tried gems like **carrierwave** and **paperclip** ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of gems which helps in file uploads.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads

Here's a simple tutorial:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/rails-image-upload-using-carrierwave-in-a-rails-app--cms-25183

Answer (score 0):

Where do you host your app? If you host on heroku you cannot write into their database so you could use an external server , e.g. amazon Web services or others like Cloudinary (for images).

[Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
[AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/)

I cannot recommend it as I do not have experience, but it offers a simple solution to image upload with carrierwave. They also have detailed setup how to's. YOu can start for free but should be aware that it is all in the cloud. 
Paperclip is fine for image upload. Think about where you want to store your images and than choose a gem for it. Tutorials can be found using Google search.
Then just make use of the

```
file_field
```

helper method